# How can I pin a Leaflet marker to a location from database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, leaflet

I have some Leaflet marker that I load from a database and I want to pin it to that location. I'm using ajax, and I don't know how to use php code in my ajax... i use the .change function but it doesn t work, any ideas?

```
    $(".edit_scoala").click(function(){
            var id_scoala = $(this).attr("id").substring(12);
            //alert(id_scoala);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/edit_scoala.php",
                data:{
                id: id_scoala
                },
                   cache:false,
                   dataType: "html"

            }).done(function(ms){
                $("#response").html(ms);
                   var map = L.map('map').setView([44.9323281,26.0306833], 12,25);

  L.tileLayer( 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVnYTYzODIiLCJhIjoiY2ozbXpsZHgxMDAzNjJxbndweDQ4am5mZyJ9.uHEjtQhnIuva7f6pAfrdTw', {
   maxZoom: 18,
   attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/"> OpenStreetMap </a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/"> CC-BY-SA </a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com"> Mapbox </a>',
   id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
  }).addTo(map);        
                    function putDraggable() {
    /* create a draggable marker in the center of the map */
    draggableMarker = L.marker([ map.getCenter().lat, map.getCenter().lng], {draggable:true, zIndexOffset:900}).addTo(map);

    /* collect Lat,Lng values */
    draggableMarker.on('dragend', function(e) { 
     $("#latitudine").val(this.getLatLng().lat);
     $("#longitudine").val(this.getLatLng().lng);
    });
   }
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    putDraggable();

    $("#id_scoala").change(function() {
     for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      if(arr[i]['id'] == $("#id_scoala").val()) {
       $('#detalii').val(arr[i]['detalii']);
       $('#latitudine').val(arr[i]['latitudine']);
       $('#longitudine').val(arr[i]['longitudine']);
       $('#telefon').val(arr[i]['telefon']);
       $('#cuv_cheie').val(arr[i]['cuv_cheie']);

       map.panTo([arr[i]['longitudine'], arr[i]['latitudine']]);
       draggableMarker.setLatLng([arr[i]['longitudine'], arr[i]['latitudine']]);
       break;
      }
     }

   var arr = $.parseJSON( '<?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>' );
    });
      });


            });

        });
```

And the edit_scoala.php file:

```
<?php
    if (isset($msg))
        echo $msg;
    include_once ("../../class/DB/DBConn.includeall.php");
    include_once ('../include/config.inc.php');
    $db = new DBconn(NULL);
    $scoala = new tableScoala($db,$_POST["id"]);
    //$scoala = $db->DbGetRow("SELECT * FROM scoala WHERE id = ".$_POST["id"]);
  echo '

<form action="" method="POST">
 <a href="?page=tabel_scoala"><span class="inchide1">Inchide</span><i class="fa fa-times-circle" id="close" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></a> 
  <h1>Modifica Datele scolii '.$scoala->row->nume.'</h1>
   <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
   <input type="hidden" name="id_scoala" value="'.$scoala->id.'" />
  <p class="form1">Nume:</p>
        <input type= "text" class= "form-control form2" style="padding:12px  20px;" name= "scoala" id="scoalal" value="'.$scoala->row->nume.'" /> <br />
         <p class="form1">Detalii:</p>
        <input type= "text" class= "form-control form2" style="padding:12px  20px;" name= "detalii" id="detalii" value="'.$scoala->row->detalii.'" /> <br />
         <p class="form1">Latitudine:</p>
        <input type= "text" class= "form-control form2" style="padding:12px  20px;" name= "latitudine" id="latitudine" value="'.$scoala->row->latitudine.'" /> <br />
         <p class="form1">longitudine:</p>
        <input type= "text" class= "form-control form2" style="padding:12px  20px;" name= "longitudine" id="longitudine" value="'.$scoala->row->longitudine.'" /> <br />
  <p class="form1">Numar telefon:</p>
        <input type= "text" class= "form-control form2" style="padding:12px  20px;" name= "telefon" id="telefon" value="'.$scoala->row->telefon.'" /> <br />
  <p class="form1">Cuvinte cheie:</p>
        <input type= "text" class= "form-control form2" id="cuv_cheie" style="padding:12px  20px;"name= "cuv_cheie"  value="'.$scoala->row->cuv_cheie.'"> <br />
<br> <br>
<p class="form1"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Salveaza"> <br> </p>
</form>
  ';



 ?>
```

I think I made a mistake somewhere.....Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you want render marker on the map from coordinates from your base or do you want to change location of existing marker?

Comment: I want to render markers on the map from base, not to change location, i do this by dragging it, the problem is, when I click on the edit button, it pins me to the center of the map, not to the coordinates of the marker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of rendering markers is querying a MySQL table/view and return the results in GeoJSON format, which is suitable for use in OpenLayers or in your case in Leaflet (I've used Leaflet as well)

Below is php code which I used:

```
<?php
#Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a GeoJSON element
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=utf8','DB_NAME','PASS',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
# Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a GeoJSON element
$sql = 'SELECT *, coor_x AS x, coor_y AS y FROM table';


# Try query or error
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}

# Build GeoJSON feature collection array
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

# Loop through rows to build feature arrays
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    # Remove x and y fields from properties (optional)
    unset($properties['x']);
    unset($properties['y']);
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => array(
                $row['x'],
                $row['y']
            )
        ),
        'properties' => $properties
    );
    # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$conn = NULL;
?>
```

Hope it helps